# Compiling a CSV, arrays or struct?

Tags: arrays, csv

I have the need to generate a CSV file. The existing code generates data sequentially. I need to write into CSV format file.
Existing data is mixture of integers and floats.
So I though to write to a two dimensional array but it doesn't work
The two dim array is meant to represent the rows & columns of the final CSV so I can arbitrarily write to any X/Y location..

```
float fArray[355*4][14];/* to save data for Data.csv */

fprintf( ascidatarep, "HAUTEUR,%2.1f,%2.1f,", fH, fC); // this works
snprintf((char *)(&fArray[0][0]),1,"%2.1f", fH); // these lines fail
snprintf((char *)(&fArray[0][1]),1,"%2.1f", fC);

printf(" [0][0]=%2.3f [0][1]=%2.3f\n",fArray[0][0],fArray[0][1]);
// C:\  [0][0]=0.000 [0][1]=0.000 // result
```

It doesn't work since I am trying to mix chars with floats, also doesn't work if I define a char[][] array since I cannot convert floats into single chars.

I guess the answer is a struct but I cannot generate one that works:

```
 struct CSV {
  char cArray[32];
  int   iArray;
  float fArray;
}tocsv[355*4][14];
```

To use this I need to know before using tocsv.cArray[0][1] that I am accessing a char and conversely when writing to the end CSV that it is a char.

There must be a neater way?

Tried your suggested two arrays @Haskell but I must have a typo I cannot find:

```
float fArray[14][355*4][1];  /* to save data for Data.csv */
char  cArray[14][355*4][5];  /*  ------------  "  ------- */

snprintf((char *)(&cArray[0][0][0]),4,"%2.1f", fH);
snprintf((char *)(&cArray[0][1][0]),4,"%2.1f", fC);
printf(" [0][0]=%4s [0][1]=%4s\n",&cArray[0][0][0],&cArray[0][1][0] );
// C:\  [0][0]= 85. [0][1]= 46.
// should print 85.1 & 46.8
```

Comment: What language? C?

Comment: You're casting the location to char*.

If you want to use a struct array you're going to have to declare it on the heap.

Just use two arrays and make it easy for yourself.

Comment: Sorry, yes, in C. Existing code written 14 years ago.

Comment: Heap? Teach a novice what is heap.  Two arrays - better idea but still have to know in which array to write/read from.